# Scroll bars that adjust based on screen resolution?

Tags: css

I have configured a page so that the table headers are stationary while the rest of the page scrolls.  Looks great in 1920x1080, but in other resolutions it does not.  This is my css;

```
.scroll 
{
max-height: 945px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Is there a way to configure it so that the scroll bars automatically adjust to the height of the screen based on its resolution, or do I need to set it up as a fixed height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a media query for that

```
@media screen and (max-height:945px) {
.scroll 
{
max-height: 700px;
overflow: auto;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Dennis - so, after I add this to my css page, what tag should I use in the html?  I used <div class='scroll'> before.

Comment: Keep the scroll class. It is important that its the same class because  then your element will change based on the person's resolution.

Comment: Weird, it doesn't seem to be doing anything.  Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, I think I needed to add an "@" before "media".  Seems to be working now.  Thanks, Dennis.

Comment: Oh geez sorry yes I will modify that

Comment: Hi Dennis - I'm trying to understand the above syntax better.  It's definitely doing something, but I find that I still have to change the max-height settings based on the resolution of the screen the page is being displayed on.  Not sure if that's how it works.  My issue is pretty typical; I need the top and bottom parts of the table to be stationary while the dynamic content in the middle is scrollable.

Comment: You may have to do that several times over. Basically anything inside the media query will apply once the conditions stated are met.

Comment: Interesting.  Dennis - one more thing.  It seems to be working in Chrome and Firefox but not Internet Explorer.  Is there a trick to getting it to work?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44734/discussion-between-dennis-fagan-and-kimomaru)